# What is the execution process for Python?

Tags: python, c

I know that Python is an interpreted language but I want to know the whole execution process. Like how a `.py` file is executed.
For example, a `.c` file is compiled into a `.asm` file then the assembler translates it into a '.o' file and finally linker links the object files to form a `.exec` file.
What's the process for python?

Comment: To be clear, Python is a language spec with multiple interpreters. There is no one answer here. Would you be satisfied with a description of how the CPython reference interpreter does things? *Usually* people referring to "the Python interpreter" mean "CPython", but it's worth checking.

Comment: There are lots of articles on how CPython runs a python script. See https://towardsdatascience.com/how-does-python-work-6f21fd197888 for one and Google shows plenty more :)

Comment: There's normally no such thing as "interpreted language". Implementation may be interpreted, but the language is usually agnostic to implementation. Python has interpreted, compiled and JIT implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Python interpreter processed the script in a sequential manner.
2. Then the code is compiled into a form of instruction set called the bytecode.
   Bytecode is a low-level language. It is an intermediate, machine-independent code which optimizes the process of code execution. So, the interpreter ignores the compilation step when executing the code for the next time.
3. After these the interpreter transfers the code for execution.
   The Python Virtual Machine (PVM) is the ultimate step of the Python interpreter process. It is a part of the Python environment installed in your system. The PVM loads the bytecode in the Python runtime and reads each operation and executes them as indicated. It is the component which actually runs your script

Answer (score 1):

After running the script you created (.py), python compiles the bytecode (.pyc) (not a set of instructions for the processor). This bytecode is a set of instructions for PVM (Python Virtual Machine). PVM executes this bytecode.

As a result:
.py -> .pyc -> PVM execution

If the .py file has changed, the system will compile the .pyc again.

Comment: No, the .pyc isn't fed to a VM. It's a side effect, a cache file, of .py compilation. Also, .pycs only appear when files are `import`ed (or when you run `compileall`).

Comment: @AKX: Substituting "bytecode" for ".pyc" in the "flow chart" given would be accurate though; even though no `.pyc` is generated, a script you run would still be compiled to bytecode in memory, then executed.

Comment: That would be more accurate, yes. :)